# fastest way to find the union and intersection items among two list

Tags: c#-3.0

which is the fastest way to find the union and intersection between two lists?
i mean.
i have two list say
**List<1>**

1

2

3

4

**Lis<2>**

2

3

Finally i need to get output as 

**List<3>**

Not Defined

2

3

Not Defined

Hope i am clear with my requirement.
Please let me know if i am conusing

Comment: Do you want the union *or* the intersection? In your example, does  "not defined" mean you don't care what happens or you want it to actually say "not defined"? Is either/both list sorted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LINQ already has Union and Intersection. Your example is neither.

```
var set = new HashSet(list2)
var list3 = List1.Select(x => set.Contains(x) ? x : null).ToList();
```

Comment: Warning: this returns nulls in list3

Answer (score 0):

Or you could do the following, which just gives you the intersection:

```
        HashSet<int> list1 = new HashSet<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
        HashSet<int> list2 = new HashSet<int>() { 2, 3 };
        List<int> list3 = list1.Intersect(list2).ToList();
        for (int i = 0; i < list3.Count; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(list3[i]);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
```